# ¿Cómo imprimir una matriz insertándole una nueva fila? JAVA

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio donde debo hacer que el usuario escoja la posición donde estará la nueva fila y los elementos que tendrá esa nueva fila. Originalmente la matriz es de 4x4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inicialización de variables
    int[][] matriz = new int [4][4];
    String decision;
    int j;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Inicialización de la matriz original 4x4 con valores aleatorios entre el 1 y el 9.
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
            matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() *9+1);
            System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
        }
    } System.out.println();

    System.out.print("¿Desea agregar una fila nueva? ");
    decision = input.nextLine();

    switch (decision){
        case "si":
            System.out.print("¿En qué posición (fila) desea insertar esta nueva fila?");
            j = input.nextInt();
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                System.out.print("Inserte el elemento " + "[" + j + "," + k + "]: ");
                matriz[j][k] = input.nextInt();
            } System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Nueva Matriz");
            //Aquí debería estar el código para imprimir la matriz nueva junto con la fila nueva 


            break;
    }
}
```

No sé cómo hacer para imprimir la matriz original junto con la nueva fila que tendrá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo debes recorrer e imprimir de nuevo tu matriz:

```
for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
       System.out.println("");
       for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
                }
 }
System.out.println();
```

Comment: ¡Gracias, me ayudó!